# diagonal separtor between two sections

Tags: html, css, image, background, linear-gradients

I want to put a diagonal line between violet header and white main, but my diagonal line is pixelated.  Moreover, the backgroud image ([the circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIxg8.png)) are still obvious (I want online white background color)
[the diagonal lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isZQ5.png)

the id of the header :

```
#circle {
    background: url("../media/circles.png"), linear-gradient(175deg, rgba(104,108,208,1) 80%, rgba(162,0,255,1), white 00%);
    height: 640px;
}
```

the html :

```
    <header >
        <div id="circle">
        ...
        </div>
    </header>
```

So, I just want the diagonal line to not be pixelated and the circle after the line not showing.

Comment: Your picture does not seem to have circles. Can you explain more what is needed? Without having access to your jpg it is difficult to know what the effect is. Could you make a runnable snippet which shows both the problems (you can copy your picture within the SO edit system) See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Comment: i add the backgroud image of the circles,

Comment: its circles with transparent background, i put violent in color with the image, but i want that the circles do not EXCEED the diagonales lines

Comment: What do you want it to look like on narrow viewports?

Comment: just background white